# apply list of values to varying range of n rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list as such

```
li=[2,4,5,7,8,9,10,26,23,28,11,3,17,10]
```

I want to create a new column in my dataframe such that 1st value in the list is repeated
8 times, the second value is repeated 8 times, the third is repeated 8 times, the 4th is repeated 9 times, the 5th 9 times, the 6th 9 times and the 7th 7 times.

The next seven values should repeat in the same pattern of numbers and then the next seven values, this goes on till the end of the df.

How can I achieve this?

I looked up np.repeat but I'm not sure how to achieve this for varying n.

Example output

```
values
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do div add 1

```
rep = [8,8,8,9,9,9,7]
np.repeat(li,(rep * (len(li)//len(rep)+1)) [:len(li)])
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.repeat` can take a list of repeat counts, so you can `np.tile` to generate the repeat counts and `np.repeat` to do them:

```
>>> li = [2,4,5,7,8,9,10,26,23,28,11,3,17,10]
>>> repeats = [8,8,8,9,9,9,7]
>>> np.repeat(li, np.tile(repeats, len(li))[:len(li)])
array([ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,
        5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,
        8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,
       10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 23, 23,
       23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 11, 11, 11,
       11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3, 17, 17,
       17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])
```

Comment: thank you this works. how ever if I have to repeat the list values each only 7 times for 365 days in the year, it generates only 364 points which leads to an error to match 365 days.